# Formpanel With Navigation to another view

Tags: navigation, sencha-touch-2, formpanel

I have a form panel. I need to navigate another view from this form panel. My View is subclass of Ext.form.Panel. I know how to navigate from Ext.navigation.View. But no idea how to navigate from form panel. Please help me.

Comment: create instance of your view, add it to viewport and then set it as an active item is view port

Comment: Can you paste me sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the instance of view or you can get pre existing instance

```
var listContainer = Ext.create("App.view.ListContainer");
```

add the instance to view port

```
Ext.Viewport.add(listContainer);
```

set the instance as the active itm with some transition effects

```
Ext.Viewport.animateActiveItem(listContainer, { type: 'slide', direction: 'left' });
```

Comment: there are two approach for this, either use navigation view in that case you will get default back button and you will have to skip the viewport code and you have to push the view, you can get example on sencha forums.

Comment: else you have to create a back button and on click of that you have to give him view object to go back to, however you will not require to add the object again once you have done that.